# Set your own marker in Google Maps - The provided image must be a Bitmap

Tags: android

I want to set my own marker in Google Maps. When I try the following I get an error

> com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.

The main part of code:

```
val markerOptions = MarkerOptions().position(map.cameraPosition.target)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.pin))

map.addMarker(markerOptions)
```

[image]

Comment: That pin is a folder. Not a file resource. Use a file. Or if you have more with the same name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a png image, not a webp or xml image.